# How to order by for 2 fields

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have table of `visitors` where `signin and signout` 2 fields for ever visitor.

I have below `array of signin and signout in jquery`

```
arr_visitors= [[3:26 P.M.,4:43 P.M.],
    [4:10 P.M.,],
    [4:10 P.M.,4:45 P.M.],
    [3:33 P.M.,3:34 P.M.],
    [3:33 P.M.,]]
```

First value of signin and second value for signout. I tried many times but not get proper output so how to them `order by signin desc, signout desc`

I used below code:

```
arr_visitors.sort (a, b) ->
          if (a[0] < b[0]) then 1 else -1
```

Output should be:

```
 [[4:10 P.M.,4:45 P.M.],
    [3:26 P.M.,4:43 P.M.],
    [4:10 P.M.,],
    [3:33 P.M.,3:34 P.M.],
    [3:33 P.M.,]]
```

Any one?

Thanks

Comment: Compare by the first element. If they're equal, compare by the second element, if present. This can be found anywhere on the web by searching for "sort by two values" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...I got solutions.

```
arr_visitors.sort (a, b) ->
          if (a[4] < b[4]) then 1 else -1
        arr_visitors.sort (a, b) ->
          if a[5] == '' or b[5] == ''
            if a[5] == ''
              if (a[4] < b[5]) then 1 else -1
            else
              if (a[5] < b[4]) then 1 else -1
          else
            if (a[5] < b[5]) then 1 else -1
```

Thanks for everybody who check my post and tried for solution.

Let me know if anybody confusion in ans i will explain it.

Thanks